# Disable 802.11n on my EVO

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, htc-evo

How can I disable 802.11n mode on my EVO?  I would like to force it to use B or G.

Comment: just for the lower bandwidth? BTW this question should also be tagged with the Evo tag

Comment: Not really an answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: TRUE ..I didn't find an add comment link on this page though. I'm curious how to know if you negotiated an n connection though!

Comment: Due to compatibility issues, I need to disable n.

Comment: I can imagine that a pre-n router might fool the phone to attempt an n connection . Fail, & try again...draining the battery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running the HTC Sense UI, then it should already be disabled.  Otherwise check [this blog post](http://areacellphone.com/2010/06/howto-enable-80211n-wifi-htc-evo-disabled-htc/) for a .zip you can flash to disable it.

Comment: My previous comment seems to have gone missing.  The stuff on that blog didn't help me.  In fact, it disabled my card all together.  I'm running 2.2, and it seems the module there is compiled for 2.1.  I have since restored back to the module from the zip file that came with my ROM.